# how to manipulate indices in a table/vector

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

Perhaps I'm missing something very basic. Could somebody guide me how to manipulate indices of a list. For example, if I have

`u = Table[Subscript[u, i], {i, 1, lp + 1}]`

I have these `u` in an expression, and I need to add a constant, say 4, to all the indices, i.e. I want to have `u` with indices from `5` to `lp + 5`. How can I obtain that?

Thanks in advance.

Saku

Comment: Saku,  welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the [introductory tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh). (3) Please remember to accept the answer that solves your problem, by clicking the  [checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t). 4) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lp = 10;
uu = Table[Subscript[u, i], {i, 1, lp + 1}]
```

> [image]

You can use [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapAt.html) to add 4 to [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) 2 of *all* elements in `uu`

```
MapAt[4 + # &, uu, {{All, 2}}]
```

> [image]

Or use [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) to replace the second part of `Subscript[a, i]` to `Subscript[a, i + 4]`:

```
uu /. Subscript[a_, i_] :> Subscript[a, i + 4]
```

> [image]

Alternatively, you can assign new values to second part of all elements:

```
uu2 = uu; uu2[[All, 2]] = 4 + uu2[[All, 2]]; uu2
```

> [image]

where I made a copy of `uu` and changed its parts.

You may find this `HowTo` page, [UpdatePartsOfAMatrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/UpdatePartsOfAMatrix.html),
useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot kguler. The second answer seems the most suitable for my purpose. I'll go through the links you suggested, and will try to help/answer whenever/wherever I can.

PS: My current reputation does not allow me to vote :( I'll do it as soon as I've reached the required level.